# Xcode simulator/device debug session with curl process taking 100% CPU

Tags: swift, firebase

I recently encountered a new issue coming most probably from Firebase SDK. As soon as I ran my app, my activity monitor quickly start to display multiple instance of curl process eating 100% of my CPU and running my macbook as hot as hell. 
The curl process seems related to googleSign and/or Firebase : 92.31.190.35.bc.googleusercontent.com:https

Stopping the debug session or closing the simulator is not enough, I have to manually kill the process to be back to normal. 
Would you have an idea of what's going on..?

[image]

Those are the Google-pods used :

````
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.6)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.13.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.4.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.6):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.4)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.1.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - FirebaseCore (6.4.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.1.1):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.1.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.7):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.0)
  - GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.6):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - GoogleDataTransport (3.1.0)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.2.1):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 3.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - GoogleSignIn (4.1.2):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMOAuth2 (~> 1.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.2.2)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.2.2)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.3.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.3.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.3.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.3.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.3.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.3.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.3.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.3.2):```
````

Comment: Im having the exact same issue did you find out what was the cause?